EventSystem not registering a BeginDrag and EndDrag Event, how to make it register the mouse input?
I am trying to create a simple drag and drop script for my card game. I cannot seem to figure out why the events are not getting detected.
Things I have tried:

Added using UnityEngine.EventSystems
Made sure there was an EventSystem in the hierarchy
Added PhysicsRaycaster 2D to Main Camera

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class DragAndDrop : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isDragging = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }
    
    public void StartDrag()
    {
        isDragging = true;
        print("drag has begun");
    }

    public void EndDrag()
    {
        isDragging = false;
        print("drag ended");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y);
        }
    }
}


However, the debug statements are not responding to my clicks. How do I make this work?
EDIT: I have attached this drag and drop script to my card prefab, which has an EventTrigger, BoxCollider2D and SpriteRenderer apart from my script in the components section. However, my public boolean isDragging does not detect anything and show a tick regardless of what I do with my Mouse...
In addition, I have tested it on a new simple project. It does not work too. When I tried to implement this, https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html, I did not get the debug message in my console.

Which object is this script attached to? What other components are also attached to the same game object?

I have edited the question, do let me know if there is anything i need to check, thank u very much

mmm. wait. why do you even think that your public methods should be called?

there are number of interfaces that your script should implement to be able to get the notifications from the event system. here is one of them, other can also be found there https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html

I was actually following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCkzlHjpe58&list=PLCbP9KGntfcFTL19eDZsWSkVMfXANF7-U&index=6
I don't understand why it worked in the video but doesn't work when I tested it out in my editor, hence the question...

The video has an essential setup part of the event trigger. That calls the script methods directly. Did you also make it as on the video?

@Morion, yes I attached the drag and drop script and also set up the BeginDrag and EndDrag events with the StartDrag and EndDrag functions...

It's now been fixed. The issue was there were other UI elements in my scene (the card description) which were blocking the raycast somehow and causing it to be not detected.
To disable it, I deselected the raycast target property on my TextMeshPro and now it works...
